# How can I store Array in a Django Model field (not using PostgreSQL)?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

What is the way to store an array in a Django Model Field?

In some cases, using a separate model/table is not performant. This is static information that not need to be indexed. I want to manage simple array in a model field.

Comment: json field would be better for your case. Or if you don't want to do much then just flatten the list and store it in comma separated values

Comment: Do you really need to store an array in the database? It is an antipattern (though there may be some valid cases).

Comment: This is static data and they do not need to be indexed. I faster to include it in the same model. I don't want to create a many-to-many foreign key relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own field class - something like:

```
import json
from django.db import models

class JSONField(models.TextField):
    description = "A field to store arbitrary python objects in JSON format"

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        if value is None or value == "":
            return None
        return json.loads(value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return value
        if not isinstance(value, basestring):
            return value
        return json.loads(value)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return json.dumps(value)

    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        value = self._get_val_from_obj(obj)
        return self.get_prep_value(value)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': JSONFormField}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(JSONField, self).formfield(**defaults)


class JSONFormField(forms.CharField):
    widget = forms.Textarea

    def to_python(self, value):
        return json.loads(value)

    def prepare_value(self, value):
        return json.dumps(value)

    def clean(self, value):
        return self.to_python(value)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and add array management (add, remove and update a single value).